# Why is one who studies philosophy called a "philosopher" rather than a "philosophile?"

Tags: philosophy-of-language

If the word "philosophy" comes from the Greek "philo-" (having a love of) and "sophia" (knowledge or wisdom) why wouldn't one who takes part in philosophy (or philosophia, in this instance) be considered a "philosophile?" It doesn't seem that there are any exactly comparable words, (if that is false, please correct me) but in near examples, Anglophilia becomes Anglophile, Xenophilia becomes Xenophile, etc. I believe that it may have to do at least somewhat with the [Old French](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/philosophie#Old_French) Influence on the word, but I'm unsure that the two factors relate directly. The inclusion of "philo-" in the word leads me to believe that the declension "phile" should exist. If the answer to this question is unclear or simply nonexistent, was there ever a point, whether it be in Greek, Latin, or any other language, that one who experienced a love of wisdom would be referred to as a "philosophile" or something similar?

Comment: I think this might be a question for a linguistics Stack Exchange, but don't take this down since it's still technically on topic.Good luck!

Comment: phile=philo, so why repeat? On the other hand, sophia means wisdom (Phronesis) shaped by the term philosophy as used by Plato, not to mean sophistry. Also in Gnosticism Sophia is a feminine figure, analogous to the human soul but also simultaneously one of the feminine aspects of God. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophia_(Gnosticism)#Syrian_Gnosis): *The oldest, the Syrian Gnosis, referred to the Sophia the formation of the lower world and the production of its rulers the Archons; and along with this they also ascribed to her the preservation and propagation of the spiritual seed..*

Comment: languages change and evolve over time. Their evolutions are not always logical, they just are. Question not related to this forum.

Comment: Why philosophile? At most "sophiephile...

Comment: Philisophile sounds like a person who wants to make love to philosophers...

Answer (score 2):

According to Lexico, the Oxford Dictionary's website, the suffixes '-phile' and '-er' have very different meanings.

[-phile](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-phile) = Denoting a person or thing having a fondness for a specified thing
[-er](https://www.lexico.com/definition/-er) (3rd definition) = Denoting a person concerned with a specified thing or subject

'-er' has 4 definitions, but the example given for the 3rd definition if you click the "More example sentences" button is 'philosopher', so that I am assuming that to be the only relevant definition.

The difference between the two is in the person's enjoyment. Imagine a person whose job was to study and write about philosophy, but hated to do so. He would certainly be a philosoph***er*** because he is concerned with philosophy due to his financial situation. However, he cannot be a pholosph***phile*** because he does not enjoy studying philosophy.

I don't think this analysis actually answers your question as to why one term is more common than the other, but it does show that they are not identical.